# Extract port number from URL and reverse proxy with Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I would like to setup my Nginx server so

```
/app/portnum
```

type URLs are reverse proxied to

```
localhost:portnum
```

E.g.

```
/app/1234
```

would be reverse proxied to

```
localhost:1234
```

Comment: can you URL's be longer, something like `/app/port/some/extra/uri` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be helpful:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name       test1.test.com;

    location ~ ^/app/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass       http://192.168.154.102:$1;
    }
}
```

Notice: If you visit `test1.test.com/app/8081`, nginx will pass the request to `http://192.168.154.102:8081/app/8081`.

More information about [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass)

Comment: Ah, managed to work it out... I had to use re-write as well.  I couldnt find the documentation anywhere which showed you could use regex groups in the location command.  Thx

Comment: Yes it work but how to remove port in url, to proxy_path, must use rewrite ?